# Prepare for submit event not called in Tapestry

Tags: forms, tapestry

I have a form in tml file of a Tapestry component.

```
...
<t:form t:id="searchForm" clientValidation="none">
    ....
    <t:select t:id="globalSport" model="globalSportModel" value="formData.globalSportId" blankOption="never"/>
    ....
</t:form>
..
```

And here is the important part of corresponding Java file:

```
...
@Property(read = true, write = false)
private ServiceSearchFormData formData;
...
@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.PREPARE_FOR_SUBMIT, component = "searchForm")
void prepareForSubmit()
{
    formData = new ServiceSearchFormData();
}
...
```

It seems to be pretty straightforward. `ServiceSearchFormData` is a DTO with few attributes and getter / setter methods. It encapsulates data submitted in the form. An instance is created on "prepare for submit" event. ... and it works fine.

However, an exception is thrown in production environment occasionally. I am not able to reproduce it. It happens in scope of POST request that submits data to this form. The exception message states:

Failure writing parameter 'value' of component MyPortal:portalindex.portalsearchform.globalsport: Property 'formData' (within property expression 'formData.globalSportId', of cz.ftm.fitsoftware.webapp.components.PortalSearchForm@3262579e) is null.

How is that possible? How can the property `formData` be uninitialized? Can this rare (but regular) exception be caused by malformed value of `t:formdata` parameter of POST request?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this much I can see, I would try two things to **narrow down the problem**:

1. I would remove the `component = "searchForm"` qualifier

   ```
   @OnEvent(value = EventConstants.PREPARE_FOR_SUBMIT)
   void prepareForSubmit()
   {
       formData = new ServiceSearchFormData();
   }
   ```
2. I would remove all the other @OnEvent annotations to see if any of those swallows this event:

   ```
   //@OnEvent(...) 
   void foo() {...}
   ```